# Android Multiple Language Support for more than 3 activities

Tags: android

I am developing android app with multiple language support

For Language Selection User Need to Select Language from a ListView

Issue: when user selects a language, it supposed to applied to all activities in app but In real, only two activities strings are changed

I have Strings for All activities in all languages

**On ListView Item Selection:**

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("LANG", "hi").commit();
                setLangRecreate("hi");
```

**setLangCreate Method**

```
 public void setLangRecreate(String langval) {
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    locale = new Locale(langval);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    recreate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this and it will work for all the activities in the application

```
Locale locale = new Locale(langval);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```